# How to Calculate Current Real RPM of a CD/DVD Drive (Not Nominal RPM) Programmatically?

Tags: c++, disk

Have you ever use some tools like Nero CD Speed Test, Opti Drive Controller, or DvdInfo?
In these applications you can get real RPM of a drive. I mean it is said that drives at the speed X have RPM Y but it's a nominal or maybe ideal RPM if you set your drive at a speed and get the RPM with these tools you will see it's a bit different and changes continuously.

For some calculation in my project I need to know the exact RPM at any time I want.
I've tested a method: reading a sector twice - from medium (not cached reading) - many times and calculating elapsed time between two reading, finally get median value. But it's a far different value from values which standard testing tools report (like tools I mentioned). For example for 24X speed, RPM should be near 5100 but any method I tested reported a strange RPM.

So how can I calculate RPM?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some measurements you've got? Also, I believe you need to use the minimal of your measurements, not the average value.

Comment: for reading a sector twice I got time difference about 28 ms but I don't know to convert it to rpm. and I use a method which I saw in SFcopy tool (decompile it, a tool for analyzing StarForce Copy Protection) and I got near 1300 for 24X but it sould be near 5100 - 5200

Comment: To convert ms you RPM you can do this: `28ms = 0.028s`. You don't know how many full rotations happened, so let it be `N`. Then rotations per second is `N / 0.028 = N * 35.7` and RPM is `60s * N * 35.7 = N * 2143`, where `N` is any natural number (1, 2, 3, etc).

Comment: But in CAV mode (Constant Angular Velocity) the rotation number is really a constant value depends on sX speed. So N can't be any number by the way if this method works (reading a sectors twice) it takes exactly one rotation because just after reading first time and get time stamp, when I command drive to read again it rotates 360 degree. See [link](http://www.google.com/patents/US20080285429) it says read an ECC Block twice and it gives rotation period, it means if reading twice takes X ms so RPM is 60000 / X. but my app gives 28 ms = 2142 RPM which is incorrect for 24X (I set it to 24X)

Comment: You cannot be sure that it took *exactly* one rotation. You can only be sure that there were N full rotations between your reads, i.e. that the sector you read is in the same position. Think about it: I assume you're measuring time from a user mode app. This app can be suspended by OS. Let's say it's been suspended for 50 ms and your code returned 56ms. Does that mean that disc is now rotating slowly? Or simply that your app 'missed' the first rotation?

Comment: And, to reiterate once again, please note that you need to take the **minimal** value of your measurements, not the average one. This is for the reasons explained above.